# Finding all points from a csvLayer within a circle with ArcGIS JavaScript

Tags: geoprocessing, csv, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am new to GIS and I am trying to develop a webpage using the ArcGIS JavaScript API. I am currently trying to figure out how to select all of the points from a CSV that are within a circle. I have the user input a location and a radius for the circle and it is drawn on the map and all of the points from the CSV are also displayed. I would like to find a way to display only the points within the circle and, ultimately, export these points to a new CSV file.

I have tried following the tutorials at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/highlight-features-by-geometry/index.html and https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=featurelayer-query but these seem overly complicated for what I am trying to do.

My code so far is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>KY Emissions Inventory</title>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />


    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.13/"></script>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>




    <script>


      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/CSVLayer",
        "esri/views/SceneView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/widgets/Slider",
        "esri/widgets/Expand",
        "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery",
        "esri/geometry/Circle",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/Color"

      ], function(
        Map,
        MapView,
        CSVLayer,
        SceneView,
        FeatureLayer,
        GraphicsLayer,
        geometryEngine,
        Graphic,
        Slider,
        Expand,
        BasemapGallery,
        Circle,
        SimpleFillSymbol,
        SimpleLineSymbol,
        Color,
        ClassBreaksRenderer
      )  {



        var map = new Map({
          basemap: "streets" //background layer
        });


        var view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
        });

        view.center = [-85.25, 37.96];
        view.zoom = 8;


        /********************
         * Add feature layer
         ********************/


         var pTemplate = {
          // autocasts as new PopupTemplate()
          title: "Facility Information",
          content: [
            {
              type: "fields",
              fieldInfos: [
                {
                  fieldName: "Facility_ID",
                  label: "National ID"
                },
                {
                  fieldName: "Facility_Name",
                  label: "Facility"
                },
                {
                  fieldName: "Pollutant",
                  label: "Pollutant"
                },
                {
                  fieldName: "Emissions",
                  label: "Emissions"
                },
                {
                  fieldName: "latitude",
                  label: "Latitude"
                },
                {
                  fieldName: "longitude",
                  label: "Longitude"
                }


              ]
            }
          ]          
        };


      /*DRAWING POINTS*/

        const less10 = {
            type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
            color: [0, 0, 255, 0.9],
            size: 4,
            outline: {
                width: .5,
                color: [1, 1, 1, 0.5]
            }
        };

        const less100 = {
            type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
            color: [212, 255, 0, 0.7],
            size: 9,
            outline: {
                width: .5,
                color: [1, 1, 1, 0.5]
            }
        };

        const less500000 = {
            type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
            color: [184, 19, 52, 0.5],
            size: 18,
            outline: {
                width: .5,
                color: [1, 1, 1, 0.5]
            }
        };

        const renderer = { //the default ones have unreadable values. scientific notation doesn't play well with these
            type: "class-breaks", // autocasts as new ClassBreaksRenderer()
            field: "Emissions", // total number of adults (25+) with a college degree
            defaultSymbol: {
                type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleFillSymbol()
                color: "black",
                size: 50,
                outline: {
                width: 0.1,
                color: [50, 50, 50, 0.6]
                }
            },
            defaultLabel: "no data", // legend label for features that don't match a class break
            classBreakInfos: [
            {
            minValue: 0.00000001,
            maxValue: 10,
            symbol: less10,
            label: "35 - 50%" // label for symbol in legend
            },
            {
            minValue: 10,
            maxValue: 100,
            symbol: less100,
            label: "< 35%" // label for symbol in legend
            },
            {
            minValue: 100,
            maxValue: Infinity,
            symbol: less500000,
            label: "35 - 50%" // label for symbol in legend
            }
        ]
        };


      /*END DRAWING POINTS*/



      /*ADD CSV FILE*/

    var fileName = "KY_NULL.csv"; //makes the page display a blank map until a pollutant is selected

    var emissionsCSVLayer = new CSVLayer({
          url:
            fileName,
            popupTemplate: pTemplate,
            renderer: renderer
        });

      function getInputFile() {
        emissionsCSVLayer = new CSVLayer({
          url:
            fileName,
            popupTemplate: pTemplate,
            renderer: renderer
        });
        map.add(emissionsCSVLayer);
      };

      getInputFile();

      const styleSelect = document.getElementById("pollutant");
        styleSelect.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
          const value = event.target.value;
          switch (value) {
            case "SO2":
              fileName = "KY_SO2.csv";
              break;
            case "CO":
              fileName = "KY_CO.csv";
              break;
            case "PT": //particulate matter
              fileName = "KY_PM.csv";
              break;   
            case "PM2.5":
              fileName = "KY_PM25.csv";
              break;
            case "PM10":
              fileName = "KY_PM10.csv";
              break;
            case "VOC":
              fileName = "KY_VOC.csv";
              break;
            case "null":
              fileName = "KY_NULL.csv";
              break;
            case "As":
              fileName = "KY_As.csv";
              break;
            case "Benzene":
              fileName = "KY_Benzene.csv";
              break;
            case "CO2":
              fileName = "KY_CO2.csv";
              break;
            case "H2SO4":
              fileName = "KY_H2SO4.csv";
              break;
            case "NO2":
              fileName = "KY_NO2.csv";
              break;     
            case "NOX":
              fileName = "KY_NOX.csv";
              break;
            case "Pb":
              fileName = "KY_Pb.csv";
              break;
            case "VinylChloride":
              fileName = "KY_VinylChloride.csv";
              break;                       
          }
          map.removeAll();
          getInputFile();
        });



        /*ADD BASEMAP TOGGLE*/

        var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
        view: view,
        source: {
          portal: {
            url: "http://www.arcgis.com",
            container: document.createElement("div")
            //useVectorBasemaps: true, // Load vector tile basemap group
          },
        } 
      });

      var bgExpand = new Expand({
          view: view,
          content: basemapGallery
        });
      view.ui.add(bgExpand, "bottom-left"); // Add to the view

      /*END ADD BASEMAP TOGGLE*/

      view.ui.add("menu", "top-right");


        /*************************
         * Create a point graphic
         *************************/

        // First create a point geometry (this is the location of the Titanic)


        var pointExists = false;
        var point = {
          type: "point", // autocasts as new Point()
          longitude: -85.970874,
          latitude: 38.407351
        };

        var pointGraphic;
        var circleGraphic;

        function makeAPoint(){
          point = {
          type: "point", // autocasts as new Point()
          longitude: parseFloat(long),//-85.970874,
          latitude: parseFloat(lat)//38.407351

        };

        // Create a symbol for drawing the point
        var markerSymbol = {
          type: "simple-marker", // autocasts as new SimpleMarkerSymbol()
          color: [1, 1, 1],
          size: 1,
          outline: {
            // autocasts as new SimpleLineSymbol()
            color: [1, 1, 1],
            width: 1
          }
        };

        // Create a graphic and add the geometry and symbol to it
        pointGraphic = new Graphic({
          geometry: point,
          symbol: markerSymbol
        });

        view.graphics.addMany([pointGraphic]);


        /*************************
         * Create circles
         *************************/


        var outerCircle = new Circle({  
          center: [parseFloat(long),parseFloat(lat)],  // longitude & latitude of current location ( obtained in another function)   
          geodesic: true,  
          radius: parseFloat(outerCircleRadius),             // radius to search within ( it is global variable initialized early)  
          radiusUnit: "kilometers"  
          }); 


        var innerCircle = new Circle({  
          center: [parseFloat(long),parseFloat(lat)],  // longitude & latitude of current location ( obtained in another function)   
          geodesic: true,  
          radius: parseFloat(innerCircleRadius),             // radius to search within ( it is global variable initialized early)  
          radiusUnit: "kilometers"  
          }); 

        var outerCircleSymb = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL,  
          new SimpleLineSymbol(  
          SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SHORTDASHDOTDOT,  
          new Color([1, 1, 1, .4]),2), new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.15]));  
        var innerCircleSymb = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_NULL,  
          new SimpleLineSymbol(  
          SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SHORTDASHDOTDOT,  
          new Color([1, 1, 1, .4]),1), new Color([255, 100, 0, 0.15]));

        outerCircleGraphic = new Graphic(outerCircle, outerCircleSymb);  
        innerCircleGraphic = new Graphic(innerCircle, innerCircleSymb);
        view.graphics.addMany([outerCircleGraphic, innerCircleGraphic]);  



        view.center = [parseFloat(long),parseFloat(lat)];
        view.zoom = 10

      };




      var lat = document.getElementById("myButton");
      var long = document.getElementById("myButton");
      lat.addEventListener("click", RespondClick);
      function RespondClick() {
        if(pointExists)
        {
          view.graphics.remove(pointGraphic);
          view.graphics.remove(outerCircleGraphic);
          view.graphics.remove(innerCircleGraphic);
        }
        lat = document.getElementById("lat").value;
        long = document.getElementById("long").value;
        outerCircleRadius = document.getElementById("outerRadius").value;
        innerCircleRadius = document.getElementById("innerRadius").value;
        makeAPoint();
        pointExists = true;
      }

        /*************************
         * End Create a point graphic
         *************************/




      });

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--<img src="logo.png" alt="logo"> -->
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>

    <div id="menu" class="esri-widget">
        <input id="lat" placeholder="Latitude">
        <input id='long' placeholder="Longitude">
        <input id='outerRadius' placeholder="Outer Radius in km">
        <input id='innerRadius' placeholder="Inner radius in km">

        <button id="myButton">Locate</button>

        <p>Choose search parameters:</p>
        <div>
          <label for="pollutant">Pollutant</label>
          <select id="pollutant">
            <option value="null">select</option>
            <option value="SO2">SO2</option>
            <option value="NOX">NOX</option>
            <option value="CO">CO</option>
            <option value="PT">PT</option>
            <option value="PM2.5">PM2.5</option>
            <option value="PM10">PM10</option>
            <option value="VOC">VOC</option>   
            <option value="As">As</option>         
            <option value="Benzene">Benzene</option>
            <option value="CO2">CO2</option>
            <option value="H2SO4">H2SO4</option>
            <option value="NO2">NO2</option>   
            <option value="Pb">Pb</option>  
            <option value="VinylChloride">Vinyl Chloride</option>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```